# Why was abortion legal when the United States was founded?

Tags: human-rights, abortion

The US supreme court recently ruled to [overturn Roe vs. Wade](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/21pdf/19-1392_6j37.pdf). Part of the decision was based on abortion laws when the 14th Amendment was ratified. While I understand that cherry picking the 14th Amendment's ratification might confront an [equal protection challenge](https://www.uclalawreview.org/the-equality-argument-for-abortion-rights/), it doesn't deal with [the fundamental finding in Roe](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/410/113). I.e. that determining a) a fetus was present and b) that the fetus died of non-natural causes would require an unreasonable search by the government in violation of an individual's 4th amendment rights. [The first 10 amendments finished ratifying in 1791](https://www.archives.gov/publications/prologue/2016/winter/poh-bill-of-rights) when [there were no abortion laws in the US](https://eastsidegynecology.com/blog/us-abortion-history-timeline/). So, if the court's originalists base their opinion on what those authors intended, why do they believe were there no laws against abortion when the bill of rights was ratified?

Comment: Your question jumps the gun. First, it is widely stated that abortion was *prohibited* under common law at the point of quickening, so the presupposition is false. Second, when referring to statutory prohibitions, the question "why did the legislature pass / not pass a law prohibiting X" is generally off topic as fundamentally political and practically unanswerable. The simple answer is that the conversion to statutory law took decades, indeed a couple of centuries.

Comment: A plausible legal history question would be "What were the common law restrictions on abortion in the US and England prior to the late 1800's?".

Comment: questions on why the law is as it is are usually off-topic, and this one con tains some incorrect assumptions. It can probably be editedm to be a reasonable question, however.

Answer (score 6):

### Of course there were laws on abortions in 1791

There just weren’t any statutes because this was handled by the common law. Under that, abortions were [legal](https://archive.org/details/whenabortionwasc00reag_0/page/n7/mode/2up) until quickening (when the mother first feels the foetus moving) and murder after that. Quickening usually takes place around 15-17 weeks. The fact that the Mississippi law makes 15 weeks the cutoff is probably not coincidental.

Comment: Do you have a citation for that common law conjecture?

Comment: @user121330 added

Comment: If this is true, (why wouldn’t it be?) then our favorite ideologues at SCOTUS sheepishly decided to forget about Amendment IX on the unenumerated rights protected, in fact, by the U.S. Constitution expressly. I would assume the relevant case laws came straight out of England. Although I am surprised to imagine what methods they may have used.

Comment: @kisspuska lots of things are legal under common law but prohibited by statute; "common law does not prohibit X" does not mean there is a right to X. Consider hacking. I'm fairly certain that hacking Stack Exchange's servers would not have been a crime in the 1700s, but that does not mean I have a constitutional right to hack SE now.

Comment: @Someone decriminalized and non-criminalized is not the same as affirmatively declaring something legal — even as a result of judicial decisions. When Dale M says it is _legal_ presuming that he said what he meant, means exactly an affirmative right. Presuming that being the case, the Ninth Amendment protects that as an unenumerated right and, frankly, even statute should not disturb that. Maybe the Supreme Court gutted that amendment already giving it the power to take away unenumerated constitutional rights, but I  not aware of such an explicit decision.

Comment: @kisspuska anything that is not forbidden is permitted; that's a basic principle of the American legal system (probably any government other than dictatorial regimes). There is no law saying I have the right to, for example, own a computer; there simply isn't a law saying I can't, so it's legal. Congress could, in theory, ban the interstate sale of computers, and a state could ban using them, but such a law does not exist, so I can use a computer. Just because something was not illegal at the time of the 9th Amendment's passage does not mean it is an unenumerated right.

Comment: "legal" means "not prohibited by law"; it does not mean "specifically allowed by law."

Comment: “this was handled by the common law[ u]nder which, abortions were legal until quickening […]” the decisional law may very well have explicitly stated that a woman was permitted to carry out an abortion (whatever form that may have entailed at the time) when deciding about whether or not it was illegal making that an explicit right. The Ninth Amendment’s purpose was exactly to protect rights explicitly granted in the common law. If that is so, Congress had no inherent power to preempt such a right unless the Supreme Court stretched one to it. This is theory, but would be worth the effort.

Comment: Just because the Supreme Court didn’t say it, doesn’t mean it’s not so. It’s not the court’s practice to consider or find legal arguments not presented by one of the parties or amicus curiae so may very well have overturned _Roe v. Wade_ aware of it, and not considering it as a matter of its practice to not cast a shadow of partiality upon themselves

Comment: @kisspuska common law rights are a subset of things the common law doesn’t prohibit. The fact that something is not illegal at common law does not make it something that a future statute doesn’t change. To be a right it has to be so fundamental that wit is sacrosanct. The right to a trial is such a right. The right to abortion probably isn’t.

Comment: @DaleM I disagree with it being probable in the sense it is more likely than not. It may or may not include such wording that set forth not only a prohibition of the King to harass women for abortion, but one that can be understood as an individual right. But, yeah, again, the Supreme Court may have decided already to gut that Ninth Amendment enough to allow statutory overturning of fundamental rights established in the common law and not enumerated in the U.S. Constitution, I have not verified.

Comment: "[O]ur law holds the property of every man so sacred, that no man can set his foot upon his neighbour's close without his leave" _Entick v Carrington_ [1765] EWHC KB J98 (_Entick_). Reading _Entick_ and the jurisprudence regarding quickening, the finding is (1) the baby until animate (today once neural activity starts, then when it moves first) is not a subject of the King, but property or the mother herself which is “so sacred, that no man can [be trespassed in, and axiomatically, the mother is free to use as they please, including destroying it.]” This is was subject of the Ninth […]

Comment: Whether or not anyone noticed it.